# OWL functional syntax parsing in Java

Tags: java, parsing, owl

I need to parse an OWL functional syntax in my Java programme but I don't want to convert it into XML/RDF. Is there any open source parser or another api(other than OWL) that I can use to parse it?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

[OWL-API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) provides support for parsing OWL functional syntax, and as it's name suggests, is a handy API for handling OWL.